# Java, threads deadlocked?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

One of my friends showed me his code below, and I thought the two threads could be deadlocked, because they could deadlock while trying to acquire locks on the different variables: `sb1` and `sb2`.

When I run the code, they don't seem to be deadlocked, as I was able to see the output:

```
A
B
second thread: AB
second thread: BA
```

**Code below:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (sb1) {
                    sb1.append("A");
                    synchronized (sb2) {
                        sb2.append("B");
                        System.out.println(sb1.toString());
                        System.out.println(sb2.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (sb2) {
                    sb2.append("A");
                    synchronized (sb1) {
                        sb1.append("B");
                        System.out.println("second thread: " + sb1.toString());
                        System.out.println("second thread: " + sb2.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

so could the two threads be deadlocked?

Comment: What would make you think a deadlock is occurring?

Comment: This code _could_ produce a deadlock. When it runs successfully, you have got lucky. If you put `sleep`s in the right places, you can ensure a deadlock.

Comment: This is like a school example of (potentially) deadlocking behaviour. That's why you acquire and release resources in the same order.

Comment: StringBuffer is thread safe, so the code using StringBuilder does not make much sense. Unless this is for demonstration purposes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that `StringBuffer` is thread safe while `StringBuilder` is not. Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are not getting a deadlock does not imply a deadlock cannot occur.

You are right in inferring that a deadlock *might* occur when two threads attempt to acquire monitors on two different resources in opposite orders.

Therefore, this code *may* produce a deadlock.

However, if any of the two threads manages to acquire both the monitors before the other, no deadlock will occur (which seems to be happening with your execution).

Here's how a deadlock might occur instead:

1. Thread one starts and acquires lock on `sb1`
2. Thread two starts and acquires lock on `sb2`
3. Thread one waits to acquire lock on `sb2`, which is owned by thread two
4. Thread two waits to acquire lock on `sb1`, which is owned by thread one

As no thread will release its lock and both wait on the other, you get a deadlock.

**Note**: as [Khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) advises, forcing the threads to sleep may prevent one of the threads from acquiring both locks first, hence producing the deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted has a *potential* deadlock. If it runs successfully, that just means you got lucky.

To demonstrate the potential deadlock, you can rig the timing to ensure that a deadlock occurs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (sb1) {
                sb1.append("A");
                System.out.println("Thread 1 has sync sb1");
                try { Thread.sleep(700); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return; }
                System.out.println("Waiting for thread 1 to sync sb2");
                synchronized (sb2) {
                    sb2.append("B");
                    System.out.println(sb1.toString());
                    System.out.println(sb2.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try { Thread.sleep(500); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return; }
            synchronized (sb2) {
                System.out.println("Thread 2 has sync sb2");
                sb2.append("A");
                System.out.println("Waiting for thread 2 to sync sb1");
                synchronized (sb1) {
                    sb1.append("B");
                    System.out.println("second thread: " + sb1.toString());
                    System.out.println("second thread: " + sb2.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Now the first thread will definitely get the sync on `sb1`, and the second will get the sync on `sb2`, and then you will get a deadlock.

Output:

```
Thread 1 has sync sb1
Thread 2 has sync sb2
Waiting for thread 2 to sync sb1
Waiting for thread 1 to sync sb2
```

Answer (score 1):

That code explains exactly a simple deadlock.

The easiest way to tell is basically because your Threads hold circular dependencies between each other.

This code alot of the times will result in a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your program can end in a deadlock. Here a more dynamic example based on the answer of @khelwood. It adds some delay to the actual string appending and repeats it in a while loop. So you can see what is happening, sooner or later the program will end in a deadlock. To identify the deadlock situation ThreadMXBean.findDeadlockedThreads() is used.

```
package stack43323164;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import java.util.List;

import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;

public class HowToDemonstrateDeadlock {

    private static List<ThreadInfo> findDeadlocks() {
        ThreadMXBean tmxb = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long[] result = tmxb.findDeadlockedThreads();
        if (result == null)
            return java.util.Collections.emptyList();
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(tmxb.getThreadInfo(result, 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        long monitorDelay=1000L;
        //You can play with the delay times to modify the results
        long threadOneDelay=100L;
        long threadTwoDelay=100L;

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        synchronized (sb1) {
                            sb1.append("A");
                            System.out.println("Thread 1 has sync sb1");
                            System.out.println("Waiting for thread 1 to sync sb2");
                            synchronized (sb2) {
                                sb2.append("B");
                                System.out.println(sb1.toString());
                                System.out.println(sb2.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(threadOneDelay);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        synchronized (sb2) {
                            System.out.println("Thread 2 has sync sb2");
                            sb2.append("A");
                            System.out.println("Waiting for thread 2 to sync sb1");
                            synchronized (sb1) {
                                sb1.append("B");
                                System.out.println("second thread: " + sb1.toString());
                                System.out.println("second thread: " + sb2.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(threadTwoDelay);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        List<ThreadInfo> deadlocks = findDeadlocks();
                        if (!deadlocks.isEmpty()) {
                            for (ThreadInfo i : deadlocks) {
                                System.out.println("Deadlock detected on thread " + i.getThreadId() + "\n" + i);
                            }
                            //Not a chance to solve the situation - boom
                            System.exit(1);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No deadlock so far.");
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(monitorDelay);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```