# Deadlock example in Multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, sleep, thread-sleep

While going through examples on Deadlock, I came across this code:

```
public class TestDeadlockExample1 {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
final String resource1 = "ratan jaiswal";  
final String resource2 = "vimal jaiswal";  
// t1 tries to lock resource1 then resource2  
Thread t1 = new Thread() {  
  public void run() {  
      synchronized (resource1) {  
       System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  

       try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}  

       synchronized (resource2) {  
        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
       }  
     }  
  }  
};  

// t2 tries to lock resource2 then resource1  
Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
  public void run() {  
    synchronized (resource2) {  
      System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");  

      try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}  

      synchronized (resource1) {  
        System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1");  
      }  
    }  
  }  
};  


t1.start();  
t2.start();  
}  
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thread 1: locked resource 1

Thread 2: locked resource 2

Timeout due to heavy load
```

According to me this is the flow:

1. Thread1 enters the sync block on resource1 and sleeps
2. Thread2 enters the sync block on resource2 and sleeps

My doubt is that if Thread1 resumed execution before Thread2 since it slept before Thread2 ,then why didn't it enter the sync block on `resource2`since by that time Thread2 must have left the sync block on `resource2` and avoided the Deadlock altogether ? Same is the doubt with why Thread2 entered the sync block on `resource1`after Thread1 left the same block before it?

Comment: Both synchronized blocks are nested in one another, until both locks are acquired, neither will be released.

Comment: So in case of Thread1, even after it resumes execution after sleep(), it wont release the lock on resource1 until it completes the sync block on resource2 inside the parent sync block on resource1?

Comment: I experimented with similar code to demonstrate the deadlock. Therefore the two methods accessing the two resources are called repeatedly in a while-loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347756/1485527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My doubt is that if Thread1 resumed execution before Thread2 since it
>   slept before Thread2

Remember the first rule of multi-threading that if you are starting 2 threads, there is no guarantee that which thread will start first, so you cannot be sure whether your Thread1 will start and sleep first or Thread2 will start and sleep first.

> then why didn't it enter the sync block on resource2since by that time
>   Thread2 must have left the sync block on resource2 and avoided the
>   Deadlock altogether ?

Notice that in both the threads, you are doing this:

- get the lock of first object
- sleep
- get the lock of second object
- release the lock of second object
- release the lock of first object

So, both the threads will get the lock first and then sleep and there is very less chance that Thread2 would have not acquired the lock of `resource2` by the time Thread1 will wake up, so almost everytime you get a deadlock.

I think this example is meant to demonstrate deadlock.

You **"might"** have not got the deadlock if:

- In Thread2, you had `try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}` before `synchronized (resource2) {`. Because with this there is slight possibility that Thread1 would have acquired the lock of `resource2` by the time Thread2 will wake up.

I think what you are missing to notice is that lock of both the objects will be acquired by the time both the threads will wake up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the threads you designed are not alone in you system, nothing guarantees that they will start immediately after you call start() nor that they will leave the sleep state synchronized. That's the whole point on deadlocked processes, because the system is constantly switching between processes (threads of processes) there might be a case where one process requires a resource that's being used by another process.You can never assume time constraints in processes unless you design a more complex synchronisation structure :/

As one of the comments explained,one of the reason for deadlocks to happen in general is that one process doesn't free the resources after it finishes using it. That's the case with you nested sync blocks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just noticed from one of the comments on this question that the sync blocks are nested..so until the child sync block completes the lock on the parent resource will not be released..Can you please confirm this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Consider, Thread1 has completed these instructions

```
synchronized (resource1) {  
   System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  

   try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Now goes to sleep and thread2 complete following instructions before going to sleep.

```
synchronized (resource2) {  
  System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");  

  try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Now when Thread1 awakes, it will try to execute

```
 synchronized (resource2) {  
    System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
   }
```

but it can't complete it's execution because Thread2 has already taken lock on `resource2`. Since it is synchronized on `resource2`, it will not execute further unless Thread2 releases lock on `resourse2`. It is classic example of **Hold and Wait**.

Similarly, when Thread2 awakes it can not execute further because it is waiting for `Resource1` which is locked by `thread1`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment section of the question, I missed out an important clue to the deadlock and that is the sync blocks are nested within each other and hence until the entire parent sync block gets completed the lock on parent resource wont be release. In order to verify, I have removed the nested braces and made the blocks independent and it seems the deadlock was avoided. Please let me know if my understanding was correct